# In Monogatari Series, What is the final conclusion of the relationship between Hitagi, Araragi and Suruga?

Tags: monogatari-series

I've been looking for a right answer to this for some time. It's kind of implied that Hitagi somehow accepts Suruga's statement.

In subsequent arcs it appears that Hitagi wants Araragi and Suruga to get along well for the sake of their relationship.

It seems to me that they got into a kind of relationship with each other, being Hitagi with Suruga and Araragi with Hitagi. I may have misunderstood or mistranslated it, but it seems Hitagi has a romantic relationship with Suruga after Suruga Monkey's arcom.

I would like to know from you if this is true, if someone who knows a lot more could explain their relationship better.